# Joomla1.5 virtuemart 1.1.7 integration users syncronization

Tags: php, joomla, integration, virtuemart

I have successfully integrated joomla1.5 and virtue-mart component.

But there is bug users not registering automatically with virtue-Mart but they are in Joomla users section. It was working fine at the time of installation.

But now there is something wrong.

Can anyone tell me how can i debug this bug  ? can anyone guess what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Virtuemart actually has its own sign up. The best option is to force everyone to sign up through virtuemart, replacing the joomla core login module etc.

The easiest way is probably to use a plugin that redirects all sign ups to virtuemart. You can find one here: http://www.keashly.net/virtuemart/kc-vm-registration-redirect